# How might I handle things when a global recruiter can’t really hire from my firm?

Tags: job-search, recruitment

Caught wind of a role with another firm that I most certainly want to attain. However, the firm hasn’t posted the position publicly. They have engaged a large global recruitment firm which is presently under contract with my current firm on a global level. This prevents them from including me.

Are there ways around this? If I drop my resume directly on the firm’s site can I then be included? Or go direct to hiring manager?

I have had no contact with the recruiter.

Comment: What is stopping you from directly applying to the role, bypassing the recruiting firm?

Comment: Hasn’t been posted publicly. If it does, I will. If they are working exclusively through the recruiter would they still be prevented from engaging with me?

Comment: I don't know of any company that will refuse to look at an application that didn't come in from the recruiter. Any exclusivity is just that the company won't actively hire other recruiters.

Comment: Location might help on this question as well. If the role is available in the US, they may be legally required to post it internally.

Comment: Thanks. U.S. firm. Role in Canada. Privately held company.  are they required to post it externally? Thanks

Comment: Clarifying the role is OUTSIDE my firm. Different company.  Headhunter can’t work with me because they have a contract with my current firm and can’t poach from.

Comment: The role outside my firm, to clarify

Comment: Your question states "role in my firm". It is not clear what the situation is.

Comment: This was incorrectly edited by someone

Comment: In the light of the rollbacks, I would just contact the firm who you would work for (and bypass the recruitment agency). You have nothing to lose, especially as you don't work for them currently.

Answer (score 5):

Inform the hiring manager of your interest in the position and ask how you can apply for it. You can move forwards from the response. But don't bypass them, they can potentially work in your favour.

Comment: Not necessarily the best idea, although it is the most obvious one; The firm has not notified internally or publicly posted this position - probably with good reason - but turned to a global recruiter, Firm may have a reason for seeking outside talent specifically - not uncommon.

Answer (score -2):

- Are there ways around this? If I drop my resume directly on the
  firm’s site can I then be included?

I don't think you have anything to lose by doing so, assuming the recuiter's posting has not explicitly stated that employees from your firm need not apply. It might even be a good idea - "Hey - this employee is right in your firm- why not use him?" - help the recruiter as well as yourself.

- Or go direct to hiring manager?

Maybe not such a good idea without doing more investigation: **Since your firm has not notified internally or publicly posted this position but turned to a global recruiter, they may have a reason for seeking outside talent specifically - not uncommon:**

- Often a firm wants 'new blood'. Perhaps they believe their current
  stuff is stuck in a rut;
- Perhaps there is someone new in the high command who has a different
  idea of how to do things and they are seeking new people that can
  carry out those ideas without any 'baggage' from within the firm;
- Perhaps there are financial considerations and they'd prefer to hire
  someone who will demand less $ than the current staff is accustomed
  to getting for such a position, etc, etc, etc...

In a large firm, 'corporate politics' are complex and volatile.
You may make your chances worse and/or be viewed as meddlesome by taking such a step. Having suffered through such situations myself, I speak from experience, not from mere conjecture.

Your firm has not notified internally or publicly posted this position, but turned to a global recruiter. There may be a good reason for that - 'more than meets the eye'.

Comment: I would contact the hiring manager and ask them the best way to apply. I don't see a problem with asking that, so long as you don't act like you expect preferential treatment.

Comment: Don't go to the 3rd party recruiter. Go to the hiring manager instead (you may be able to save your company some money if you do that). If the hiring manager refers you to the recruiter, that's fine too. Then state in your communication with the recruiter that the hiring manager told you to contact them about this position. If you're able to say this to the recruiter, then I can guarantee you the the recruiter won't screen your resume out. No one wants to be accused of losing a resume, or screening out a candidate, that a hiring manager might want to hire.

Comment: I would upvote either of these comments if posted as an answer.

Comment: Can you explain more about the not uncommon reason for seeking outside talent? And why can't they just say "sorry, you'll need to contact the outside recruiter" in that case? The risk of being seen as "meddlesome" seems minimal to me.

Comment: @mattfreake - see revised answer, where I elaborate on your point.